# How can i create a custom object in Salesforce with a '__' in the name?

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to check if a change tables exists in Salesforce by calling

```
        var name = "acme_npsp__Allocation_c__c";
        try
        {
            salesforceObject = _service.describeSObject(name);                
            return sObject;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;                
        }
```

but it gives an error:

```
        INVALID_TYPE: salesforceObject type 'acme_npsp__Allocation_c__c' is not 
        supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the 
        '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for 
        the appropriate names.
```

(107 - FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION) Cannot create a new component with the namespace: acme_npsp.  Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API.

But if i replace the __ in the middle with a single _ it seems to work , but that isnt my object in salesforce so i cant reference it in other code.

Salesforce doesnt allow to create such an object with '__' in the middle, but it was created using the package Nonprofit Success Pack (NPSP) which can be downloaded from the store.

How can i create the object with the '__' in the middle , ie after the npsp ?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not allow `__` in API names, because double underscores serve a special meaning: they delimit the components of the API name. An API name, for a schema element like this, consists of up to 3 parts:

`namespace__component_name__c`

`namespace` is the first component, and is the (optional) namespace, which indicates that the component is part of a package. NPSP's namespace is `npsp`. You cannot create components in a namespace you do not own.

The name element is present on all components. For `Account` and other standard objects, it's the entire API name.

`__c` is the suffix, which indicates what kind of entity you have. `__c` is a custom object; `__b` a BigObject; `__e` a custom Platform Event; `__mdt` a custom Metadata Type. Lack of a suffix indicates a standard component.

---

Your question does not make much sense as written. You appear to be trying to work with the object `npsp__Allocation__c`. It's not clear why you are trying to prepend some other value to the namespace and suffix.

Accessing the describe does not create an object, so the behavior of your code is exactly as designed.

Comment: I actually try to create a change table to keep a track of my change triggers. If for example it was Account object , I would create a change table name as Acme_Account__c , there is no namespace here, but because npsp__Allocation__c has a namespace npsp, i want to create a tracking change table as Acme_npsp__Allocation__c. It wont let me because of the different namespaces. Thats what im trying to overcome.

Comment: You simply cannot do that. You'll have to architect this differently. I'm not sure what a change trigger is, but the Salesforce platform natively offers Change Data Capture and Field History Tracking.

Comment: So basically i create and keep track of changes to entities. So if a user lets say changes a field in salesforce depending on what my trigger is tracking changes for , I update the table.

Comment: That's fine, but you can't name your sObject that way. You'll have to come up with a different naming pattern.

Comment: So really if another package is installed that has yet a different namespace , same issue . So really i could have a number of different namespaces ?

Comment: Yes, the user could have an arbitrary number of namespaces installed. But you have to know what the object is called to have a trigger on it, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: I have an object npsp__Allocation__c installed from a managed package. Now i want to prefix it with my own prefix , as above acme so i am wanting acme_npsp__Allocation__c, but it thinks the namespace is acme_npsp because of the double __. Is there a way to ignore the double _. I can remove it when i create the object, but the api name will change to acme_npsp_Allocation__c,  and when i try to access fields , it will be looking for npsp__Allocation__c, custom object which now doesnt exist ?

Comment: As I've said several times, you cannot do that.